# Responsive Div Table

Tags: html, css, grid, responsive, css-tables

I tried generating a div table from this website: http://divtable.com/generator/

However, everything is working fine except for the responsiveness of the Div Table. When minimizing the browser width, I'd like it to be fully responsive. For example, I would only want it to show two items per row on mobile devices.

Here's the code I'm using for it:

```css
.divTable{
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
 text-align: center;

}
.divTableRow {
    display: table-row;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: table-header-group;
}
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
.divTableHeading {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: table-header-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableFoot {
    background-color: #ffffff;
    display: table-footer-group;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.divTableBody {
    display: table-row-group;
}
```

```html
<div class="divTable">
<div class="divTableBody">
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone4Parts.png?11283548812375177185" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 4 Parts</div>
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone4sParts.jpg?3165596616796717679" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 4s Parts</div>
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone5Parts.jpg?8873682526308780626" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 5 Parts</div>
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone5cwhite.jpg?647508470520316270" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 5c Parts</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone5sParts.jpg?8873682526308780626" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 5s Parts</div>
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhoneSEParts.jpg?647508470520316270" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone SE Parts</div>
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone6Parts.jpg?18059291597630475032" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 6 Parts</div>
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone6PlusParts.jpg?9610561940146358986" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 6 Plus Parts</div>
</div>
<div class="divTableRow">
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone6sParts.jpg?11014928492319611631" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 6s Parts</div>
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone6sPlusParts.jpg?8400309241132689431" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 6s Plus Parts</div>
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone7Parts.jpg?7760410424665462960" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 7 Parts</div>
<div class="divTableCell"><img src="//cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone7PlusParts.jpg?9544342566201088259" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 7 Plus Parts</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have bootstrap included. Why don't you use the grid?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest you to use bootstrap, I redesigned your code using bootstrap CSS style. I used for the large desktop the col-md-3 class. This class gives each one of the div including your images a width of 25% when the screen is larger then 992px, consequently each "row" div will have 4 column at this set width. 
When the screen is smaller then 992px, but larger then 750px I applied col-sm-6 that let the screen just have 2 Images for row. The width of col-md-6 in the bootstrap.css file is set at 50%.
The maximum number of columns in bootstrap are 12, col-sm-6 means 6 columns span. For the small devices I just used a media query for maximum size of 320 px, the smartphone will only display 1 item for row.
The media query let you set custom css rules for a specific windows width.
You can check the below code and learn to use bootstrap on many websites or at the following link:

http://getbootstrap.com/

When you use bootsrap, you will need to include in your head file, before your main.css file the link to the bootstrap CDN or your local bootstrap file. You should include this bootstrap file, before your stylesheet, so that you can overwrite this rules with your custom rules.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 divTableCell"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone4Parts.png?11283548812375177185" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 4 Parts
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 divTableCell"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone4sParts.jpg?3165596616796717679" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 4s Parts
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 divTableCell"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone5Parts.jpg?8873682526308780626" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 5 Parts
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 divTableCell"><img src="https://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/1606/7271/files/iPhone5cwhite.jpg?647508470520316270" alt="" width="200" height="200" /> <br />iPhone 5c Parts
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

This is the css

```
.divTableCell, .divTableHead {
    border: 1px solid #ffffff;
    /*display: table-cell;
    padding: 3px 10px;*/
    text-align: center;
}

@media (max-width: 320px) { 
    .divTableCell {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want a responsive table....Use Bootstrap library,
create a

```
<table class="table-responsive">
<tbody class="table"></tbody>
</table>
```

and you are good to go...read more here:

http://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/content/tables/
http://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_tables.asp

NOTE: setting the width and height in Pixel is always not a good practice if you want a specific div to be responsive. Because Pixel sets a FIXED width and height of the div that wont change size no matter what.

you can try the bootstrap library, or set the width and height to percentage

```
width="100%"
```